# Hiding unwanted columns in shiny output

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I need help to hide the unwanted columns from my shiny output. My dataset has columns like Description.Source, Description , category, Month, count and Percentage. Right now based on the above selection in my output$mon i require the selection to be applied on my dataset but it should show only the count and percentage columns in my rendertable output.

Below is the the code of my shiny server output,

```
output$mon <- renderTable({ 
filter(data_shiny_mon, Description.Source == input$source, ifelse(Description.Source == 'online', Description == input$e_source1, ifelse(Description.Source == 'offline', Description == input$e_source2, Description == input$e_source3)), 
category %in% input$checkGroup, Month %in% input$month_details)})
```

Regards,
Mohan

Comment: Just add `[, c("count", "Percentage")]` after your filter

Comment: @warmoverflow Thank you very much... That's the solution I was expecting....